# Performance between SQL IF EXISTS and code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*I did google this but **Visual Studio Code** is obscuring results. Similar Questions (while posting this) also isn't helpful.*

I realize that it will vary a bit per language, version, and edition, but I expect the modern languages are highly efficient at passing queries off to databases and, of course, `if`s.

Let's say I have this query

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products P WHERE pName = 'Gadzooks')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Products(pName,pDescription)
        VALUES('Gadzooks','Thingamajig')
        SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NEWID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS NEWID
    END
```

Is there a performance difference between that and [psuedocode]:

```
var CheckProducts = [SELECT pName from Products where pName = 'Gadzooks']

if (CheckProducts.length > 0) {
  return "Gadzooks already exists, blargh!";
} else {
  [INSERT INTO Products ...
   SELECT @@IDENTITY as NEWID]
}
```

Comment: Probably not a lot of difference but using EXISTS means you only need a single database call instead of two. Side note, you should avoid using @@IDENTITY here. You should instead use SCOPE_IDENTITY. If there is a trigger on your table you will get the identity of the inserted row inside the trigger and now the row you inserted in Products.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange re: SCOPE_IDENTITY. Yeah, it's a little cleaner this way, anyone looking at the query knows everything it does immediately and can even easily return a custom error message. There are, of course, times when the 'duplicate' process is more than a simple error message and it makes sense to break down to code.

Comment: As Sean says it will be minor but bear in mind that EXISTS returns true/false (i.e. a bit indicator) whereas SELECT name will return however many bytes of data that name is. Whilst the SQL query will likely perform the same seek or scan, there will be additional IO overhead plus the traffic to your app.

Comment: @NickFry Are you saying this self-contained query should be written a different way? Would you mind posting an answer that showed this?

Comment: No, you asked if there was a performance difference, whilst there is likely to be minimal difference in the actual query execution there will be a greater impact on IO and network traffic, again, small but the difference between moving 1 bit and however many bytes the name consumes